# Flutter Web Page blank white screen how to fixed?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, web, sdk

No project is working in Flutter, I installed the sdk and installed android studio, I am using vs code, my stable version, but I could not solve some kind of error. please help
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109789
[Code value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KioV.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your flutter web app with html renderer and see if it works.

Paste this command to your terminal:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KZQg.png)

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been solved thanks to this command. I couldn't solve this problem for about 1 week. I contacted some developers, but none of them could solve it, thanks for your interest.